# syntax error near unexpected token '(' in python script

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a python script to input values from data in an excel sheet into a web application. I'm currently stuck as I get the following message when I try to run the script "sh: -c: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `('"

Below is my script

```
import os
import time
import pandas as pd

source_path = 'excel_file_path'
API_KEY = 'api_key'
source_file = pd.ExcelFile(source_path)
dfs = {sheet_name: source_file.parse(sheet_name) for sheet_name in source_file.sheet_names}
for index, row in dfs.items():
    cmd = "cmd /k 'curl -X PATCH https://translation.io/api/v1/segments/{SEGMENT_ID}.json -H \"content-type: application/json\" -d\"{{ \'api_key\': \'{API_KEY}\', \'target\': \'{TARGET}\' }}\'".format(SEGMENT_ID=row['id'], API_KEY=API_KEY, TARGET=row['target'])
    print(cmd)
    os.system(cmd)
    time.sleep(1)
```

It looks like there is an issue with the Print function. I want it to take the value of whatever 'cmd' is equal to above for the "SEGMENT_ID" and "TARGET" variables.

Let me know if you can assist or need more information. I use python on a Mac.

See below full trace when trying to run the script from Mac Terminal

```
Last login: Tue Jul 21 14:02:59 on ttys000
(base) MacBook-Pro-2:~ lespesmunozthomas$ python /Users/lespesmunozthomas/Desktop/2M/Operations/Tanda/excelcmdprompttestfr.py
cmd /k 'curl -X PATCH https://translation.io/api/v1/segments/0      8534085
1      8534086
2      8534087
3      8534088
4      8534089
        ...   
312    8534397
313    8534398
314    8534399
315    8534400
316    8534401
Name: id, Length: 317, dtype: int64.json -H "content-type: application/json" -d"{ 'api_key': '5aba962e7e1c4be68b01e3bcd3edb643', 'target': '0      Laisser un blanc pour la valeur par défaut ("%...
1                                                  Lundi
2                                                  Mardi
3                                               Mercredi
4                                                  Jeudi
                             ...                        
312                                        Pas d'en-tête
313    N'affichez pas d'en-tête (pas de description d...
314                                                    ,
315                               Séparateur de colonnes
316                                             Dimanche
Name: target, Length: 317, dtype: object' }'
sh: -c: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 11: `Name: id, Length: 317, dtype: int64.json -H "content-type: application/json" -d"{ 'api_key': '5aba962e7e1c4be68b01e3bcd3edb643', 'target': '0      Laisser un blanc pour la valeur par défaut ("%...'
```

Cheers
Thomas

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. This compiles fine without a SyntaxError. Can you post the full error message, including the stack trace?

Comment: The shell is trying to run the script, rather than Python.  How are you trying to run this?

Comment: Hi @jasonharper, I'm running it in Mac Terminal. I've added the full command in my question above.

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: Python 3 @scenox

Comment: Seems that `("%` is causing the problem, do you have this string in the Excel file?

Comment: If you see your output. the `print(cmd)` clearly worked.

Comment: Yes @scenox, the 1st cell in the target column has the following value "Laisser un blanc pour la valeur par défaut ("%{valeur}")"

Comment: Why are you trying to run `cmd` on a Mac?  Why is your shell command hundreds of lines long?  Why are you using curl rather than something in-process like `requests`?